# TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter, how to open a contentpane again once its closed

Tags: infragistics, docking

I am using TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter from Infragistics for displaying ContentPane in TabGroupPan to having Docking functionality. I don't know if I am doing something in correct. The problem that I am having is once the contentpane is closed from the TabGroupPan. I can no longer start it again.

I am using MEF. The way I originally opened the view is through RequestNavigate API.

```
Uri viewNav = new Uri("View1", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.WorkspaceRegion, viewNav);
```

and the other thing I noticed is, as soon as contentPane is closed OnViewsCollectionChanged is not invoked. Does this mean that View is still present in the region. If corrent then should I be just able to navigate it again.

Comment: Still waiting for answers...would be grateful for you inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics doesn't provide a TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter so I am not familiar with this.  The only.  The only region adapters that Infragistics provided were on codeplex and haven't been updated in the last three years:
http://ncal.codeplex.com/

Doing a search on Google, I did find the following blog post and this may be what you are using (though this hasn't been updated in three years either):
http://claudiopi.blogspot.com/2008/07/infragistics-tabgrouppane-region.html

I haven't done any testing though I looked at the code and it appears as though the TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter should be updated so that the CloseAction of the ContentPane is set when the ContentPane is created rather than only when the views are removed as the panes are already closed when the CloseAction is being set with the current implementation.

There are more details on the CloseAction of a ContentPane here:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DockManager.v11.2~Infragistics.Windows.DockManager.ContentPane~CloseAction.html

Note that if the OnViewsCollectionChanged isn't being fired in the TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter, you should set a break point on the if statement in OnContentPaneClosed to see if the if Statement evaluates to true or false as that is where the view is being removed.